# Easiest way to test Google Script code that is part of a web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am a few hundred lines of code into developing a Google Apps Script web app, with code that I have mostly tested as I went (thank you, GAS, for making the back-end language basically JavaScript, so that I could test in-browser). However, I am in the process of moving some of the functions and classes that I wrote on the client-side onto the server-side (the server end should have those functions, too, as its job is to serve the data!), and adding a few methods on the server side.

I would like to know how best to test this code I'm writing on top of what I'm implementing, without having to move it to client-side (or JavaScript console) every time that I write it. It would be nice to have results and tests that I can actually persist, without having to clutter my browser's console's command history.

Comment: You could write all output into a text file

Comment: Take a look the [Trouble Shooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I just created another google apps script project in another google doc. It's the easiest way for me.